Delphi 12.1 fails to start Android debug session with manifest file error
I have a 64-bit FireMonkey Android app written in Delphi 11.1 that needs to be updated to Android API level 34 for the Google Play store.  I installed Delphi 12.1, and updated the SDK to API level 34.  The app compiles without error, but when I try to deploy to a Samsung S21 running Android 14 (API 34), I get the following error:
[MSBuild Error] The "CreateAndroidManifestFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.CreateAndroidManifestFile.genManifestFile()
   at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.CreateAndroidManifestFile.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)

How do I resolve this error?
I tried updating the min and max versions of the API level in the manifest file.

Please include your manifest file since the error seems to be in there

@Marsroverr the error does not appear to be related to the contents of the manifest file, but with the syntax of the file path used to save the manifest file.

In my Release version setup, the Output Directory and the Unit output directory were missing.  Once I updated those settings to .$(Platform)$(Config), the issue was resolved.  I now have an issue with a missing package name in my AndroidManifest.xml...:  
